# c# write in word file

Tags: c#

i need to write two different variables with different fonts on the same line, like "Organization naame" + "Adress".

But c# edits the entire line fully.
My try:

```
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Document.Open(FileName: @str_Path);
doc.Paragraphs[int_row].Range.InsertBefore(Organization);
doc.Paragraphs[int_row].Range.Font.Italic = 1
doc.Paragraphs[int_row].Range.InsertAfter(Adress);
doc.Save();
app.Documen.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such behavior is that you set the font style of whole paragraph when you use `Range.Font` property. One of the possible solutions is working with `Document.Words` collection. Find your word and set `Font` property personally to it.

Comment: _"The reason of such behavior is that you set the font style of whole paragraph when you use Range.Font property"_ - It is not the fault of `Range.Font` rather the starting and ending character positions the OP used when creating the range, namely `doc.Paragraphs[int_row].Range....`.  Thus the subsequent `...Range.Font.Italic = 1` is applied to the whole paragraph indexed by `int_row`.  Looping through `Document.Words` would be very tedius and doesn't scale